# Use pdo fetch_group to save sql count as individual variables

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, count

I'm trying to do a sql COUNT with php PDO::FETCH_GROUP to avoid using three separate sql queries

```
$genders = $db->query('SELECT COUNT(memberID), gender FROM members WHERE gender IS NOT NULL GROUP BY gender')->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_GROUP);
```

The array for this looks like:

```
Array ( [3] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [gender] => Female [0] => Female ) [1] => Array ( [gender] => Male [0] => Male ) ) [2] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [gender] => Unknown [0] => Unknown ) ) )
```

And while I can print that using a foreach within another foreach loop it's not really what I want.

I've tried also to use bindColumn with a while loop:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT m.gender, COUNT(*) as count FROM members m WHERE m.gender IS NOT NULL GROUP BY m.gender');
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_BOUND);
$stmt->bindColumn('count', $count);
$stmt->bindColumn('gender', $gender);
while ($row = $stmt->fetch())
    {
        echo $gender.' - '.$count.' ';
    }
```

But although they both work I want to know if it's possible to save each of the counts in relevant variables?

e.g. $femaleCount, $maleCount, $unknown etc

Comment: Is there any specific reason for not using arrays? Otherwise you can easily create an array with genders as it's keys and counts as it's value with only one loop

Comment: Just that I want to echo them separately on the page, it's part of a an admin dashboard

Comment: Again I'm confused, What part of using an array will prevent you from echoing them separately?

Comment: I obviously don't know enough about arrays, I can't see how I would split the array above to echo each gender separately. Can I be cheeky and ask for a hint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of FETCH_GROUP you need [PDO::FETCH_KEY_PAIR](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/fetch_modes#FETCH_KEY_PAIR). The link is to my article where I listed all the fetch modes explaining their purpose and possible use.

```
$sql = 'SELECT gender, COUNT(*) FROM members WHERE gender IS NOT NULL GROUP BY gender';
$data = $db->query($sql)->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_KEY_PAIR);
foreach ($data as $gender => $count)
{
    echo "$gender - $count\n";
}
```

Comment: Your article is awesome! That's what I've been using to try and learn pdo with php, I was so focussed on trying to use fetch_group that I didn't notice key_pair would work better, thank you

Answer (score 1):

I'll use your second query and change it a little bit. Overall, your queries are OK, but you have to use an `Associative array` to store your data in it and then use it in your code.

The query will be like this:

```
$strSQL = 'SELECT gender, COUNT(*) as member_count FROM members WHERE gender IS NOT NULL GROUP BY gender';
```

Since you are not passing any variable to your query, then there is no need to user `prepare` just use a simple `query`

So the code will be like this:

```
$arrMembers = array();

$strSQL = 'SELECT gender, COUNT(*) as member_count FROM members WHERE gender IS NOT NULL GROUP BY gender';
$result = $db->query($strSQL);
while($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    $arrMembers[$row['gender']] = $row['member_count'];
```

Now you have an array with the name of `$arrMembers` with all the returned records form the query in it. The key of each row of the array is "gender" and the value of the row is "member count"

So after this you can use this code to echo the number of members of any gender in your code:

```
echo $arrMembers['Female']; // Will print number of female members
echo $arrMembers['Male']; // Will print number of male members
echo $arrMembers['Unknown']; // Will print number of members with unknown gender
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this is magic! I will investigate associative arrays as I can see this will be very useful